# How to combine multiple notifications into one?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a notification system for my website, so, when a user reacts with an emoji or comment, it adds a notification document on this firebase subcollection `users/{userID}/notifications`. Right now, if a user clicks on 5 different emojis, it creates 5 documents under the `notification` subcollection and shows all 5 notifications on the UI. But I want to combine it to 1.

Do I need to combine the documents on the UI or on the backend and how?

I call this function to add a `notification` document to the `notifications` subcollection:

```
 const { addNotification } = useFirestore(
    `users/${authorUserID}/notifications`
  )

// call this function when user click on any of the emoji
addNotification({
          authorUserID: authorUserID,
          userId: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
          solutionID: id,
          solutionTitle,
          isRead: false,
          isReaction: true,
        })

export const useFirestore = (collectionName) => {
  const addNotification = async (doc) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })

    try {
      const createdAt = Timestamp.now()
      const addedDocument = await addDoc(collection(db, collectionName), {
        ...doc,
        createdAt,
      })
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ADDED_DOCUMENT", payload: addedDocument })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error.message })
    }
  }

  return {
    addDocument,
  }
}
```